# Creating 'wing' corner trick with pure css

Tags: css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

Is it possible to add corners like this image (top corners)? I'm not sure what the effect is called. If it is, what would be your approach?

Update:
There were some who suggested that this question is a duplicate, unfortunately, the solution to the duplicate does not take into account that the 'wings' are filled in with color. While it works great for a tab that has an outline, this has an actual fill.

What is this technique Called?

[image: Weird corner trick]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to use the `:before` and `:after` pseudoclasses to add and position the corner tips.

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  width: 400px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

em {
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.2em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid gray;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.box:before {
  left: -6px;
}

.box:after {
  right: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <em>Benefits Included In Members Savings Package</em>  
</div>
```